# boilerplate for Foundation 5 with SASS support

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

Hey guys i tried so many options for installing Foundation with SASS.
Now they don't give us the option of downloading  sweet .rar of .zip file which i can customize.
I have to install bower, gems etc which i find very annoying. is there any link to foundation 5 boilerplate including sass.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the command line, install something like http://mixture.io/ - which gives you a graphical interface for the compiler (& more)

Comment: can u tell me how to use Mixture?

Comment: Download, install, launch it. Create new project, select empty directory. You then get a choice of frameworks to use as the basis to your project, of which foundation is one. By default it uses the sass version. in the scss folder, there's a file called _settings.scss, which contains all the sass variables you need to customise the look of foundation. Each time you modify and save the file, Mixture will precompile the sass files and launch a small webserver on which you can preview your site.